# Firebase - How to get all posts where someone commented in the last x days

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to receive a list of posts where someone posted a comment in the last 2 days from the Firebase realtime database.

```
const currentTime = Date.now();
const twoDaysAgo = currentTime - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Database.ref(`posts`).orderByChild(`comments/{comment}/createdAt`).endAt(twoDaysAgo).on('child_added', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in the orderByChild part because I'm receiving all the posts.

My database structure looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Queries in the Firebase Realtime Database can only order/filter for a value that is at a known path under each child. Your `` .orderByChild(`comments/{comment}/createdAt`) `` does not work. For more on this, see [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested) and [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).

As usual when working with NoSQL databases, the solution is to change your data model to allow the use-case. In this case, you can add a `lastCommentAt` property to each post, and update that whenever you write a comment to a post. With that new property in place, the query becomes:

```
Database.ref(`posts`).orderByChild(`lastCommentAt`).endAt(twoDaysAgo)...
```

---

On a separate note: your nesting of the comments under the posts themselves violates some of the recommendations that the Firebase documentation makes about data modeling. Specifically, you should [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flatten data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) to ensure that the [data scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout).